# Procedure or function 'procMakeTimeSlot' expects parameter '@userFriendlyErorrMessage', which was not supplied

Tags: asp.net

I keep getting this error, I'm working with Visual Studio 2016 and Microsoft Management Studio SQL Server 2016.

> Procedure or function 'procMakeTimeSlot' expects parameter
>   '@userFriendlyErorrMessage', which was not supplied.

and

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //.Net says anything not select operation is a non query

    create proc procMakeTimeSlot 
    (
       @appointmentId int,
       @appointmentSlotId int,
       @userFriendlyErorrMessage varchar(100) output 

    )
    as 
    begin 


    declare @successfulInsert bit; 

    begin try 

    insert into ApptTimePeriod 
    (AppointmentId, AppointmentSlotId)
    values 
    (@appointmentId, @appointmentSlotId)

        set @userFriendlyErorrMessage = 'Successful';

        set @successfulInsert = 1;

    end try 

    begin catch 
    --primary key error 

        if (ERROR_MESSAGE() like'%pkApptTimePeriod%')

        set @userFriendlyErorrMessage = 'Appointment has already been added to the time slot'


         if(ERROR_MESSAGE() like

'%fkAppointmentTimePeriodToAppointmentSlot%')

         set @userFriendlyErorrMessage = 'Invalid Time Slot';

          if(ERROR_MESSAGE() like '%fkAppointmentTimePeriodToAppointment%')

             set @userFriendlyErorrMessage = 'Invalid Appointment';


                  if(ERROR_MESSAGE() like '%chSlotsLeft%')

                         set @userFriendlyErorrMessage = 'No time Slots Available';

                         set @successfulInsert = 0;

                         end catch 

                         return @successfulInsert;      
    end

/* 


declare @userFriendlyErorrMessage varchar(100);

execute procMakeTimeSlot

@appointmentId = 10005,

@appointmentSlotId = 100,

@userFriendlyErorrMessage = @userFriendlyErorrMessage output;

print @userFriendlyErorrMessage;



<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FindServiceAvailability.aspx.cs" Inherits="VehicleServiceWebAppMcConnell.FindServiceAvailability" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<asp:Calendar ID ="calStartDate" Caption ="Choose start date (optional)" runat="server" />

    <asp:Calendar ID ="calEndDate" Caption ="Choose end date (optional)" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID ="btnFindServiceAvailability" Text ="Find Service Availability" runat ="server" OnClick="btnFindServiceAvailability_Click" /> 

<asp:GridView ID ="gvAvailableServiceTimes" Caption = "Available Service Dates and Times" runat ="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="False" EmptyDataText = "No availability for requested date / time" >

<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Select Date and Times">

        <ItemTemplate>

            <asp:CheckBox ID ="cbSelectedDateTime" runat = "server" />

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:BoundField DataField ="AppointmentSlotId" HeaderText ="Appointment Slot ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField ="ApptDate" DataFormatString = "{0:d}" HeaderText ="Available Date" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField ="ApptTime" HeaderText ="Start Time" />


</Columns>

</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID ="btnMakeAppointment" Text ="Make Appointment" runat ="server" OnClick="btnMakeAppointment_Click" /> 

<asp:Label ID ="lblResultMessage" runat ="server" />

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Where is your .Net code?  What are you passing for @userFriendlyErorrMessage?

Comment: Just added it i know AppointmentSlotId is spelled correctly in my procedure in Microsoft management studio (SQL)  for procMakeTimeSlot

Comment: Let me know if you need to see my visual studio code. Or even the entire solution i'm sure its a very small error one of my friends said i had to declare the userfriendlyerrormessage as a varchar but i have already done that? maybe i have to do it in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@userFriendlyErorrMessage varchar(100) output
```

Try using this

```
@userFriendlyErorrMessage varchar(100) = null output
```

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested same error occurs when i rebuild / start with out debugging.

Comment: Or Else Remove Output Parameter and try to return value using select statement. Just a like below

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @GETDATETIME DATETIME,@GETDATE DATE
SET @GETDATETIME = GETDATE()
SET @GETDATE = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE(),105)
SELECT @GETDATETIME AS DATETIME,@GETDATE AS DATE.

try Like this Remove Output Parameter and return Output using Select Statement. Sample i have mentioned

Comment: Just was  a spelling mistake thanks for help had error and erorr mixed up in userfriendlyerrormessage